# Excel 2010 equation editor access via C#(VSTO)/ VBA

Tags: c#, excel, vba, editor, equation

I need to get access to Equation Editor that's built in Excel 2010. In Word2010 it's quite simple as it provides OMath interface to access it via C# or VBA. There's no such thing in Excel eventhough it's possible to insert equations this way. Has anyone solved this problem ?
I need to extract the equation from the eqution object in a text way (no metter if it's Latex, MATHML or any other language. It just has to be a single string)

Of course I can use MathType to do this (Actually I've alredy done this with MathType) but I don't want to force the User to buy MathType as  Excel has built in feature that would do the trick.

Comment: I have deleted my answer as you apparently know how to add the EQ Editor :) I am not sure how to extract the equation as plain text.

Comment: Actually I don't exactly know what you mean about adding the EQ editor ? You mean how to add the equation (the Word 2007/2010/Excel 2010 one) to excel worksheet ? If so I'd be grateful if you could show me this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an OLE object first, as mentioned in this link?

http://www.techyv.com/questions/it-possible-equation-editor-vba-excel-2010

I don't have an enormous amount of experience with Excel's equation behaviour but it seems Excel doesn't use the OMath object. As far as I understand:

You can add a new Equation with:

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Equation.3", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False)
```

And subsequently, you can access these objects using the OLEObjects collection:

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Item(1)
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to get the equation from the control as string (no metter in Latex,MathML or something) and Equation.3 does not allow me to do so.